# Right Click Multiextended listbox to highlight only one option

Tags: .net, winforms, powershell, listbox, mouseevent

I have a multiextended listbox and when I right click on an item in the box I want only that item to be selected. I can't change the `SelectionMode' of the listbox because when I left click it has to be able to select multiple items.

Here is the code I have that works when the listbox is a single select box:

```
$inputboxSelectedServers.add_MouseDown({                    #listbox click event
    [System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs]$e= $args[1]
    if ($e.Button -eq  [System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons]::Right){
        $index = $inputboxSelectedServers.IndexFromPoint($e.Location)
        $inputboxSelectedServers.SelectedIndex = $index
        $Menu2.Show($inputboxSelectedServers, $e.X, $e.Y)   #contextMenuStrip
    }
})
```

But I can't figure out how to change the right click mouse behavior to select only the listbox item the mouse actually hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after a while of tinkering, inspiration hit. All I had to do to have the `MultiExtended` listbox have only one item selected on a right click was to deselect every other item. In this code, the `for` loop deselects all the items in the listbox, then the `SelectedIndex` property is set to the item where the mouse right clicked.

```
$inputboxSelectedServers.add_MouseDown({
    [System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs]$e= $args[1]
    if ($e.Button -eq  [System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons]::Right){
        for($i=0;$i -lt $inputboxSelectedServers.Items.Count; $i++){
            $inputboxSelectedServers.SetSelected($i,$false)
        }

        $index = $inputboxSelectedServers.IndexFromPoint($e.Location)
        $inputboxSelectedServers.SelectedIndex = $index
        $Menu2.Show($inputboxSelectedServers, $e.X, $e.Y)
    }
})
```